# Printing each JSON input path from a complex JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose I have the following JSON object:

```
{"root":{"Child":0, "Child1":0, "Child2":[0, 0, 0, 0]}}
```

This JSON object may be complex.

I'm interested in printing each input path from my complex JSON object in JQUERY. My output should look like:

```
{"root":{"Child":0}}
{"root":{"Child1":0}}
{"root":{"Child2[0]":0}}
{"root":{"Child2[1]":0}}
{"root":{"Child2[2]":0}}
{"root":{"Child2[3]":0}}
```

How would you print a complex JSON object in this way without specifying the name of JSON variables in Jquery?

Comment: for(var item in json) then your actual item is in json[item] assuming that json is your variable. It doesn't really use anything from jquery, but is still my most  favourite approach. Otherwise try the comment from @Tyranicangel that works also and uses jquery

Comment: But you should to specify which variables from your JSON object you are interested in. If my JSON object included many different variables, it would be rough to  specify every variable in Jquery. @Tyranicangel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are looking for it, but this looks weird though :P

```
var obj = {"root":{"Child":0, "Child1":0, "Child2":[0, 0, 0, 0]}};
for (var item in obj){
  if(typeof obj[item] == 'object'){
    for (key in obj[item]) {
      if (obj[item].hasOwnProperty(key)) {       
        if(typeof obj[item][key] == 'object'){
          for(var keyValue in obj[item][key]){
            //console.log(obj[item][key][keyValue])
            console.log('{'+item+':'+'{'+key+':'+obj[item][key][keyValue]+'}}') ;  
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log('{'+item+':'+'{'+key+':'+obj[item][key]+'}}') ;  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried a recursive approach to print all properties.

```
     var json={"root":{"Child":0, "Child1":0, "Child2":[0, 0, 0, 0]}}

     function prettyPrint(json,path,depth)
     {
      var keys=Object.keys(json);    
      if(keys.length==0)
     {   
       var outp=path+":"+json;
       for(var i=0;i<depth;i++)
       {
        outp+="}";  
      }
       console.log(outp);
     }      
     else
     {    
      depth++;  
      for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
      {  
        prettyPrint(json[keys[i]],path+":{"+keys[i],depth);    
     }
    }
  }  

  prettyPrint(json,"",0);
```

Output is

```
    {root:{Child:0}}
    {root:{Child1:0}}
    {root:{Child2:{0:0}}}
    {root:{Child2:{1:0}}}
    {root:{Child2:{2:0}}}
    {root:{Child2:{3:0}}}
```

Alter this fiddle to suit to your needs

http://jsfiddle.net/cwmgwok4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dirty jQuery (since your question is tagged) version:

Demo1@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/a8k6t2bf/3/)

Demo2@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/a8k6t2bf/5/)

```
var json = $.parseJSON('{"root":{"Child":0, "Child1":0, "Child2":[0, 0, 0, 0]}}'), arr = [], arrVal;

$.each(json, function(key, val) {
    if (typeof val === "object") {
        $.each(val, function(key1, val1) {
            if (typeof val1 === "object") {
                $.each(val1, function(key2, val2) {
                    arrVal = ['{"', key , '":{"', key1, '[', key2, ']":', val2, '}}'].join("");
                    arr.push(arrVal);
                });
            } else {
                arrVal = ['{"', key, '":{"', key1, '":', val1, '}}'].join("");
                arr.push(arrVal);
            }
        });
    }
});
```